# Build Angular application with Spring boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I want to build an Agular application, but I don't know how to build a project structure.

I have found 2 ways to build the Application. The first way that I chose was to build together Spring boot application and Angular application. The Second way was to build separate projects. With the first way, I can get access to static resources easily, but I think It is not a good way.
With the second way, It is good because I can use Spring boot application for web and mobile clients.

Do I need suggestions on how to build spring-agular like projects? The basic problem is how to use effectively static resources in an angular project?

Answer (score 2):

I have a project that uses Spring boot as backend and angular in the front. For us, it was better to serve angular using the spring boot. But you can do it in another way.

In a brief, spring boot works as an API to make CRUD, authentication, and others tasks we need. To serve angular in spring, you need to build your project with `ng build --prod` and copy all files generated here to the static folder in spring. Nonetheless, you need to adjust the routes and make a proxy (I'll show it).

To adjust the routes, you may include the following configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class AngularConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

      registry.addResourceHandler("/**/*")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
        .resourceChain(true)
        .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver() {
            @Override
            protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath,
                Resource location) throws IOException {
                Resource requestedResource = location.createRelative(resourcePath);
                return requestedResource.exists() && requestedResource.isReadable() ? requestedResource
                : new ClassPathResource("/static/index.html");
            }
        });
      
    }
}
```

In dev phase, it is very boring to build angular. So, it's very desired using `ng serve` (with the spring up, of course). As angular cli serves on `localhost:4200` and spring on `localhost:8080`, you have to make a proxy between the address:

1. In the project root you must include a file named `proxy.conf.json` containing:

   {
   "/api": {
   "target": "http://localhost:8080",
   "secure": false
   }
   }
2. Next, in the file `package.json`, replace `"start": "ng serve"` to `"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"`

There you go! It should works.

Finally, it's very boring copy and paste the build. So, if you're using maven, you can include a rule to make it for you every time you start spring. Put it in your `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                      <execution>
                          <id>copy-resources</id>
                          <phase>validate</phase>
                          <goals><goal>copy-resources</goal></goals>
                          <configuration>
                              <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/static/</outputDirectory >
                              <resources>
                                  <resource>
                                      <directory>${basedir}/../frontend/dist</directory >
                                  </resource>
                              </resources>
                          </configuration>
                      </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Of course, you should set the paths according to your project.

TL;DR: you can work with to projects in the dev phase and include the build in the spring for production.

Comment: Thanks, I understood but If I don't copy an angular project to spring boot's static folder and instead f this, I run an angular project  (with port=9900) together with spring boot project (with port=8080). I want to say If I run the projects separate environment not the same, It works well or not?. I have never built an angular project with API. I write only backend side using Java.

Comment: Yes, you can do that! You can let spring just as an API server. However, you need to serve angular using another server (Apache server, for example). The front end made with angular cannot "serve itself". In addition, it's very probable you'll need to set the CORS in your API server (have a look in this [post](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors).

Answer (score 0):

My personal suggestion;

> [JHipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/) is a development platform to generate, develop and deploy Spring Boot + Angular/React Web applications and Spring microservices.

Comment: I think, JHipster is not a good choice for building a robust application